# what happened between getSqlSession and openConnection

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

My springboot + mybatis service is very slow, and I analysis the log and find this:

```
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:06.295] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:97) [Creating a new SqlSession]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:06.296] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.registerSessionHolder(SqlSessionUtils.java:148) [SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@584909b4] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:17.997] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:87) [JDBC Connection [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.ConnectionProxyImpl@1ebfd05a] will not be managed by Spring]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:17.998] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:181) [==>  Preparing: SELECT `id`,`name`,`sales_group_id`,`advertiser_id`,`agent_id`,`industry_id`,`contract_id`,`cast_system_id`,`traffic_category_id`,`distinct_type_id`,`dsp_id`,`dsp_name`,`push_ratio`,`executor_name`,`direct_sales_name`,`agent_sales_name`,`description`,`region_id`,`customer_type_id`,`creator_id`,`creator_name`,`create_time`,`update_time`,`audit_status_id`,`run_status_id`,`version`,`begin_date`,`end_date`,`cipdx`,`progress` FROM campaign_info WHERE id = ? ]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:17.998] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:181) [==> Parameters: 1(Integer)]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:19.107] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger.debug(BaseJdbcLogger.java:181) [<==      Total: 0]
[DEBUG 2018-06-11 15:30:19.107] [http-nio-9973-exec-1] logid:102789834531274752 org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.closeSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:191) [Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@584909b4]]
```

there is about 10s gap between `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession` and `org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection`, so what happened?  Is it my mysql is slow? Or something error in my spring service?

Answer (score 1):

The main suspect is opening connection to database as that is happening at that time.

You are using connection pool so it quite possible that all connections in the pool were busy and this particular client was waiting all that time until some connection is returned to the pool.

To check if this is the case you can either check connection pool documentation on how to enable logging of when connections are borrowed/returned to the pool or enable `DEBUG` logging for `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils` logger.

Another possible reason is that opening connection is slow. You can check this using some simple program (like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)) that uses jdbc to connect to the database directly.